# File Not Found for classLoader.getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, maven, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I want to read a .properties file in my project at run time.
The project structure is as shown in the screenshot.

My code is as follows

```
public void getDefaultConfigurationView() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Problem starts v40.0");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = context.getClassLoader();
        System.out.println(classLoader.toString());
        if (classLoader != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "classLoader is not null");
            InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("twitter4j.properties");
            if (inputStream != null) {
                properties.load(inputStream);
            } else {
             throw new FileNotFoundException("twitter4j property file not found");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "classLoader is null");
        }

        System.out.println("end of read");     

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This method fails to read the twitter4j.properties file which is clearly in the jar generated by maven.
The stacktrace is as follows:

```
03-10 20:10:54.111: I/ambientTwitterNewRuntime(25859): Problem starts v40.0
03-10 20:10:54.111: I/System.out(25859):     dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.ambientdynamix.core-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.ambientdynamix.core-1]
03-10 20:10:54.111: I/ambientTwitterNewRuntime(25859): classLoader is not null
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859): java.io.FileNotFoundException: twitter4j property file not found
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at org.ambientdynamix.contextplugins.ambientTwitterNew.ambientTwitterNewRuntime.getDefaultConfigurationView(ambientTwitterNewRuntime.java:91)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at org.ambientdynamix.core.DynamixService.doContextPluginConfigurationView(DynamixService.java:2382)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at org.ambientdynamix.core.DynamixService.openContextPluginConfigurationForFramework(DynamixService.java:2356)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at org.ambientdynamix.ui.adapters.InstalledPluginsListAdapter$4.onClick(InstalledPluginsListAdapter.java:212)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-10 20:10:54.111: W/System.err(25859):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My maven pom file contains this.

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: ReUpload Image as it is too small .

Comment: take a look at the directory target/classes after performing "mvn package".

Comment: Did you try `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("twitter4j.properties")` ?

Comment: @Ulrich , i think this will work when `properties file` is in same package . Isn't it ?

Comment: Where exactly is your properties file "twitter4j.properties" located?

Comment: @NeerajJain , I think you have to put the properties file in src/main/resources , if you are using maven,

Comment: Yes I have tried that. Same result; a nullpointer is thrown. Is this picture clearer now. twitter4j.properties file is in src/main/resources as shown in the screenshot

Comment: put twitter4j.properties in "org.ambient...ambientTwitterNew" package and write "PluginFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("twitter4j.properties");" it might work

Comment: That did not help @rns

Comment: @user77005: can't you show the "tree" of the jar. This provides more information than the file structure...

Comment: @NeerajJain , yes, my proposal will work when the file is located in the same package as "YourClass" (in my short example). If you write `/twitter4j.properties` , the file will be searches in root directory of the application, where the packages "com" , "org" ... etc are located